# How do I send an email during stripe payment after a purchase in python? Why is my example not working?

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am trying to send the email with the code from here in python. https://stripe.com/docs/receipts

I added it in the code below. The problem is the email isn't getting the email.

I based the code on this https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/accept-credit-card-payments-in-flask-with-stripe-checkout .

The db has a User table, which contains the user information this includes the email, as the one and the many table ,which contains the Payment table which include the payment/donation + email columns. In the payment table you don't need to logged in to make a donation.

routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint , render_template, redirect, url_for, request, abort, flash

from app.payment.forms import EmptyForm, EmailForm 


import stripe

# might need to adjust templates  
payment = Blueprint('payment', __name__, template_folder='templates')

from flask_login import current_user

# import db from flaskblog folder in __init__.py.
from app import db

from app.models import User, Payments

from redmail import outlook

import os

@payment.route('/donations', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def donations():


    form = EmailForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ''' 
        This convert from float then u mulitply by 100 to get the cents. An ex int ex .55 then get 55.0
        Then convert from float to int then to string because request.form... is a str.
        '''
        price_of_donation_form = str(int(float(request.form["number"]) *100) ) # Make global variable? 
        if not price_of_donation_form:
            flash('You did not type in a donation price.')
            # 307 redirects to the route while being a POST request
            return redirect( url_for('payment.donations.html'), code=307 )
        email_form = form.email.data
        payment_db = Payments(price_of_donation=price_of_donation_form, item_name='Donate' , email=email_form) 
        db.session.add(payment_db) 
        db.session.commit()
        #add_foreign_key(email_form)        
   
        # The variable I pass on has to be id in url_for.
        
        flash('donations are successful')
        # 307 redirects to a POST request
        return redirect(url_for('payment.order', item_name_db=payment_db.item_name), code=307)
    
    return render_template('stripe_payment/donations.html',  form=form, title=' Give donations')




  




# route/webhook 

@payment.route('/order/<item_name_db>', methods=['POST'])
def order(item_name_db):

    # if the payment_db does not exist get a 404 error
    payment_db = Payments.query.filter_by(item_name=item_name_db).first_or_404()
    # variable for 'order/success/<email>'
    #payment_db_email = payment_db.email  
    '''
    you can only purchase one product at a time, but since line_items is a list, 
    you can select and buy multiple products if you add a shopping cart interface
    ''' 

    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(   
        # The line_items argument specifies the product that the user wishes to buy.
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': payment_db.item_name, 
                    },
                 
                    # automatically converts to decimals/float
                    'unit_amount': payment_db.price_of_donation,
                    'currency': 'usd',
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            },
        ], 
        # prefill the email input in the form.
        # I use this so I don't have 2 different emails in 2 different forms.  
        customer_email=payment_db.email,
        # payment_method_types argument allows what payment you want/allow.
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        # mode specifies what type of payment you want. An example is payment is a one time payment. 
        mode='payment',
        # stripe will redirect to one of these pages upon the form completion. How?
        success_url=request.host_url + 'order/success',
        cancel_url=request.host_url + 'order/cancel',
    )

        # send email after payment/donation
        stripe.PaymentIntent.create
    (
        amount=payment_db.price_of_donation,
        currency="usd",
        payment_method_types=["card"],
        receipt_email=payment_db.email,
        description="3% of your purchase goes toward our ocean cleanup effort!",
    )


    return redirect(checkout_session.url)




@payment.route('/order/success')
def success():
    return render_template('success.html', data=data)


@payment.route('/order/cancel')
def cancel():
    # send email 
    return render_template('cancel.html')
```

The code donations.html is basically a counter with an email form and a counter for money. I don't think there is a need to include it unless someone wants me to .

I also have some html that I didn't include the success and the cancel html files but they are just simple html forms with basically messages saying your order is a success or failure.

Comment: Are you running this in testmode? If yes, as mentioned in the Stripe documentation : Test payments created using your test API keys don’t automatically send receipts. Instead, you can view or manually send a receipt using the Dashboard.

Comment: I am running this in my ide so I assume that is test mode. Sorry I didn't notice that. Thanks

Comment: its entirely possible to run the code in your ide using the production api keys. Stripe's api has a test api key that would act like @alex stated, but just because you are running it in an ide does not mean you are running it with their test api.